# How to disable automatic GZIP for response

Tags: spark-java

As I've learned from [Spark documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#gzip) GZIP is done automatically for response if it contains *Content-Encoding* header with value *gzip*.

I have the following code:

```
post("/test", (req, res) -> byteArray);
```

What if `byteArray` is already compressed with GZIP? Then Spark will compress it once again and client will receive a garbage.

Is there any way to response with GZIP without Spark auto-compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to response with GZIP without Spark auto-compression?

Unfortunately not. You could write your response directly by using the writer on the underlying `HttpServletResponse`.

```
post("/test", (req, res) -> { 
    res.raw().getWriter(); // do something with this writer 
    return "";
);
```

It's not pretty though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to opt out of Spark's automatic GZIP compression.

One somewhat grotesque workaround is to wrap the InputStream in a GZIPInputStream and return that from your controller method:

```java
return new GZIPInputStream(myInputStream);
```

**HUGE CAVEAT:** This will waste CPU cycles on what is effectively a no-op of unzipping and re-zipping the stream, but given that Spark has no opt-out it can serve as a temporary workaround.

I encourage anyone who is running into this issue to voice a feature request in the Spark 3 [feature request thread](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/1105#issuecomment-600239799).